# Get current html from google chrome current tab

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-chrome, webkit

**What i want to do:**

I want to get the html of the current tab **from** google chrome
**what i dont want to do:**
Get the current tab **url** and then use `webClient.DownloadString` to get the html.
(I already did it)


It is very important to me to get the html from google chrome and not from the current google chrome url.
What i have tried:

```
WebKit.NET
```

WebKit.NET let me navigate into url **like** google chrome.

i want to "`connect`" into the current google chrome window, and then into the current tab window, insert the current tab document into `WebKit.DOM.Document`.

on other project i used `SHDocVw.ShellWindows` (ShellWindows = all supported windows), the SHDocVw let me get the current html of the current tab of `internet explorer`.
Example:

```
    Dim shellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    For Each Ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer In shellWindows
            Dim htmlDoc As mshtml.HTMLDocument = Ie.Document
    Next
```

SHDocVw works with `Internet Explorer` **only**.

How can i browse between chrome tabs and then insert the html into strings list?

I suspect that the answer lies in `WebKit.Interop.dll`, But I have no experience with this library.
I believe that someone has a solution to this question,
The classname of the tab window is `Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND` (by using spy++),
I think that i cant get the html from current tab `Handle`, 
But maybe i can convert the handle to `WebKit.DOM.Document` - But I prefer to check the first option.

It is extremely important to me to make the project in the right way and the best possible way.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to work with the WINAPI `GetWindow`. There you can pass the classname and get the handler of the current window / process. I don't know directly if this work but all tabs in Google Chrom run in an own thread so I think it is possible.

```
Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetWindow" ( ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wCmd  As Long) As Long
Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessage" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Keys, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Long
```

That are the functions you need. Then you can send a instruction to the thread with the second WINAPI `SendMessage` and get the HTML from the side. I think you have to get the classname of the HTML frame inside the tab. Or maybe you have to call `GetWindow` again to get the HTML frame I don't know the structure of Google Chrom but I think with spy++ it is easy to get the classnames for that.